# How do I embed tables here on Super User?

Tags: support, formatting

I've seen some Excel questions where people post a question about current excel table format and desired format, where they show mock-up of the table.  How do I create one of those?  (I am unfamiliar with the display here.)

Answer (score 5):

You can format raw data by

- indenting it by 4 spaces, or
- pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> shortcut after selecting the text, or
- clicking the `{}` button in the editor, or
- wrapping your text in `<pre></pre>` tags

Please use the preview window below the editor to check if the formatting looks right.

Alternatively, format your tables with a web application as ASCII. See: [Is there a webapp to create ASCII art tables?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables)